# How do I use a multiple and statement in excel

Tags: excel

My formulae is:

```
=IF(AND(OR($G4=34503,$G4=36313,$G4=42028,$G4=46889),$J4,{1;2}),IF(BA3="",BA3,BA3&CHAR(10)&CHAR(13))&"*"$I4,BA3)
```

The above all works fine, but I need to include:

```
$H4="What, if anything, of the instructors performance enhanced your learning experience"
```

The above is (I gather) a second and criteria but not linked to the `J4` formulae in that

If any of the `G` numbers have either the item in `H` or the item in `J` then carryout the function.

Also how do I truncate the text for the `H4` criteria?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Include `H4` where? G numbers have H or J? Truncate H4?

Comment: I want to add H4 before J4 so that if any of the G reference numbers link to the text string in H4 or the array in J4 then carryout the rest of the function.  By truncating I just want, if possible, to reduce the text string by using wildcards.

Comment: `add H4 before J4 ` that doesn't mean anything XD There are quiet a few places that you can add before `J4`. Also, `G reference numbers`? You mean those cells? And they don't link to any text string in H4. Edit: you don't seem to understand what your formula is doing and I am going home.

Comment: Column G contains question IDs from differing surveys but all linked to a specific topic.  Versions of the survey had weight codes against the possible question responses i.e. 1 or 2 means a positive response (those weights are contained in column J.  So a question ID Linked to a weight will return the qualitative response that is held in column I.  The issue is that the older generation surveys didn't have a weight value, for the question ID, all I can reference it to is the actual question text which is in column H.

Comment: Are you sure **'all works fine'** ? It seems to me that the portion containing `... ,$J4,{1;2}), ...` is malformed and may not be doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: Yeah all works fin until I try to add the and criteria in that if G equals and H equals the carryout the function.  The J is similar if G equals a specified ID and J equals a specific code the n carry it out.  Perhaps it's too many ands as the ; is an and within the array.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the elements in an AND() statement does not matter. You currently have this AND() statement:

```
AND(OR($G4=34503,$G4=36313,$G4=42028,$G4=46889),$J4,{1;2})
```

If you want to add the condition `$H4="What, if anything, of the instructors performance enhanced your learning experience"` then simply include it between the round brackets of AND()

```
AND(OR($G4=34503,$G4=36313,$G4=42028,$G4=46889),$J4,{1;2},$H4="What, if anything, of the instructors performance enhanced your learning experience")
```